# How to do a Hive JOIN on two tables based on a field inside a JSON?

Tags: json, join, hive, hiveql

So I have two tables created like so:

```
create external table test1 (json string) stored as textfile location '/user/data/test1';
```

```
create external table test2 (json string) stored as textfile location '/user/data/test2';
```

Both the tables have a single column as string which internally contains a JSON object.

Here's how I do a typical select of a field named `name` from the tables:

```
select get_json_object(json, '$.name') from test1 limit 1;
```

...which uses the `get_json_object` UDF of hive to parse the JSON string.

Now, I need to do a test1 LEFT OUTER JOIN test2 based on the `name` field in JSON objects. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.*, t2.* --select columns needed
from
    (select t1.*, get_json_object(json, '$.name') as name from test1 t1) t1 --add more filters
    left join 
    (select t2.*, get_json_object(json, '$.name') as name from test2 t2) t2 --add more filters
    on t1.name=t2.name
```